# How to obtain a list that counts 'None' matches and positive matches when using Rgex.findall(text)?

Tags: python, web-scraping

this is my first post and I will try to be as complete as I can:

I am trying to perform my first web scrubbing program using Python. I am studying the coronavirus and am trying to obtain the data myself from pages that upload the rawdata.
The main goal is to create a dataframe with "Day of Month" "New Cases (cases)" and "new deaths (death)"
as well as country and provinces, but I will ask about these two in another question.

So far with the imported libraries I am able to scrub the elements of the html file, in particular the `<li>` elements and `<h4>` elements.

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(#Purposefully left blank)

#names of my lists

cases = [] 
death = []
Country = [] 
Province = [] 

#the page i'm scrumming

driver.get("https://bnonews.com/index.php/2020/01/timeline-coronavirus-epidemic/")

content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

#Regex for finding ["Any number" + new + case(s)] in a <li> element

newcaseReg = re.compile(r'''(
\d+\s\bn?e?w?\scases?\b
)''',re.VERBOSE)

#Regex for finding ["Any number" + new + death(s)] in a <li> element

deathcaseReg = re.compile(r'''(
\d+\s?\bn?e?w?\sdeaths?
)''',re.VERBOSE)

#Regex for finding ["in province(s), country"]

provconReg = re.compile(r'''(
\bin\s\w+?.*?
[?\s\bprovince?s]
?[,\s]
?\w+\..?
)''',re.VERBOSE)

#Regex for cleaning the country and province regex and returning a list with only the names

SepProvConReg = re.compile(r'''(
[A-Z]\w+
)''',re.VERBOSE)

#variables that contain all the <h4> and <li> elements of the page. 

h4Tag = str(soup.findAll('h4'))
liTag = str(soup.findAll('li'))

#Cleans string and adds the amount of new cases per <li> element to "cases" variable

for i in newcaseReg.findall(liTag):
    cleanNCReg = re.compile(r'''(
    \d+
    )''', re.VERBOSE)
    cases.append(str(cleanNCReg.findall(i)))

#This is supposed to append "0" when deathcaseReg.findall(liTag) == 'None' and also append "value" when
#deathcaseReg.findall(liTag) finds the regex. 

for i in deathcaseReg.findall(liTag):
    if i == 'None':
        death.append('None')
    else:
        death.append(i)



len(cases)
```

So the output for "cases" is 1950+, but the `len(death)` is 284. This is because the regex is only counting the positive results and not appending "0" like I want it to. This is where I need help because I've searched and checked and the answers from: [How to return a string if a re.findall finds no match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56855558/how-to-return-a-string-if-a-re-findall-finds-no-match) didn't help me at all because the output keeps returning 278 (having used all answers from that result search).

One more question:
Since I am trying to build a column based dataframe for analyzing my data in R I was wondering if anybody could think of a way to write a code that would repeat the `<h4>` element for the same amount of `<li>` tags corresponding to that `<h4>` tag:
What I mean is, suppose

```
<h4> 4th of March <\h4>

<li><\li>
<li><\li>
<li><\li>
.
.
.
x50
<h4>3rd of March<\h4>
<li><\li>
.
x30
<h4>2nd of March<\h4>
```

So what I would like is to write a code that would identify the number of `<li>` between the first `<h4>` and the second `<h4>` and to create a list that repeats the `<h4>` string that amount of times.

Any help would be well appreciated. Thank you for taking your time to read this.

Comment: Can you edit your question with a short sample of your desired output?

Comment: Thank you, I think the question now has that format.

Comment: There are about 50 `<h4>`s in the page. Do you want the `<li>`s between each pair or only between the first and second? Also, between a target pair - what excactly is in the " list that repeats the <h4> string that amount of times"?

Comment: What I need is for the `<h4>` titling the subsequent `<li>`s to be repeated the exact amount of times as there are subsequent `<li>`'s.
So the idea is that between 2 `<h4>`s there are x amount of `<li>`s that correspond to the first `<h4>` value. I need to repeat the `<h4>`'s value that x amount times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your regex don't match the "None" string (literally).

```py
import re

death_case_re = re.compile(r"\d+\s?\bn?e?w?\sdeaths?")
match = death_case_re.search("None")
print(match.group() if match else "(don't match)")
# => (don't match)
```

When you loop over the sentences, you can use the following regex `r"(First|\d+) \s+ (?: new \s+)? cases?"` to match the case(s) and a similar regex for the deaths.

For instance:

```py
import re


sentences = """\
23:59: 3 new cases in San Marino. (Source)
23:59: 1 new case in Fairfax County, Virginia, United States. This is the first case in Virginia. The patient is a U.S. Marine assigned to Fort Belvoir who recently returned from overseas business. (Source)
23:50: 2 new cases in Thailand. (Source)
[...]
22:42: First case in Washington, D.C. (Source)
22:41: 2 new cases and 1 new death in New South Wales, Australia. (Source 1, Source 2)
22:34: 1 new case, a patient who has already died, in Argentina. This is the first death in South America. The patient was a 64-year-old man who had traveled to Paris, France. He had underlying health conditions. (Source 1, Source 2, Source 3)""".splitlines()

FLAGS = re.VERBOSE | re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE
for sentence in sentences:
    mo = re.search(r"(First|\d+) \s+ (?: new \s+)? cases?", sentence, flags=FLAGS)
    if mo:
        cases = mo.group(1)
        cases = int(cases) if cases.isdigit() else 1
    else:
        cases = 0
    mo = re.search(r"(First|\d+) \s+ (?: new \s+)? deaths?", sentence, flags=FLAGS)
    if mo:
        deaths = mo.group(1)
        deaths = int(deaths) if deaths.isdigit() else 1
    else:
        deaths = 0
    print(f"{cases} case(s), {deaths} death(s): {sentence}")
```

Output:

```
3 case(s), 0 death(s): 23:59: 3 new cases in San Marino. (Source)
1 case(s), 0 death(s): 23:59: 1 new case in Fairfax County, Virginia, United States. This is the first case in Virginia. The patient is a U.S. Marine assigned to Fort Belvoir who recently returned from overseas business. (Source)
2 case(s), 0 death(s): 23:50: 2 new cases in Thailand. (Source)
0 case(s), 0 death(s): [...]
1 case(s), 0 death(s): 22:42: First case in Washington, D.C. (Source)
2 case(s), 1 death(s): 22:41: 2 new cases and 1 new death in New South Wales, Australia. (Source 1, Source 2)
1 case(s), 1 death(s): 22:34: 1 new case, a patient who has already died, in Argentina. This is the first death in South America. The patient was a 64-year-old man who had traveled to Paris, France. He had underlying health conditions. (Source 1, Source 2, Source 3)
```

**EDIT**

In you peculiar case, you need to loop over the `<li>` tags, and get the string of each tag, for instance:

```py
import re

FLAGS = re.VERBOSE | re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE

for li_tag in soup.findAll('li'):
    sentence = str(li_tag)
    mo = re.search(r"(First|\d+) \s+ (?: new \s+)? cases?", sentence, flags=FLAGS)
    if mo:
        cases = mo.group(0)
        cases = int(cases) if cases.isdigit() else 1
    else:
        cases = 0
    print(f"{cases} case(s)")
```

Comment: Thank you so much Laurent! I will take a look at the code and update the results. I especially like your use of Regex. It took me so long to make mine, and yours seem so simple and clean!

Comment: I seem to hace one little problem with your resolution.

`sentence` is a string. I think in my code `liTag` is also a string. But for some reason, when I run in with my code where instead of "sentence" I use "liTag" the output gives me 0cases for each character in each li. What I mean to say is that it seems to check each character in every `<li >`string and checks it with the REGEX

Comment: @PabloRodriguez: In you peculiar case, you need to loop over the <li> tags, and get the string of each tag. See my EDIT.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me with this Laurent. I learned a lot and your code was very clear.

Comment: You're welcome. So, you can upvote and accept this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers